# PIC32 data storage in flash change / corrupt

Tags: pic, microchip, flash

I have some random issue with data saved in flash on PIC32MX470F512L.

Since there is no EEPROM, part of the flash storage is used to save configuration and some statistics (ie.: reboots reason, errors on serial communication, etc).

Over about 50+ units, randomly part of configuration change, the cause is not found but some hypothesis for the moment :

- No capacitor on MCLR
- Reading of the configuration in flash before VDD fully stabilized
- Power off during flash write

I am sure there is not enought writes to go beyond limit, somewhere between 1 and 25 writes per day.

Yet I've not been able to reproduce the issue periodically.

Here are some relevant parts of the code...

**Main**

```
int main()
{
    /* Variables defines */

    //Configure l'horloge systeme
    SYSTEMConfig(GetSystemClock(),SYS_CFG_WAIT_STATES | SYS_CFG_PCACHE);


    //Active le watchdog (periode de timeout de 8sec)
    EnableWDT();

    //Initialisation de la configuration non volatile
    config_init();

    /* Other init stuff */

    //Gestion des statistiques de demarrage.
    if(mGetWDTOFlag())
    {      //Reset par watchdog
        mClearWDTOFlag();
        g_stConfiguration.stats[STAT_REBOOT_WATCHDOG]++;
        config_saveStats();
    }
    else if(mGetPORFlag())
    {  //Reset par switch
        mClearPORFlag();
        g_stConfiguration.stats[STAT_REBOOT_NO_POWER]++;
        config_saveStats();
    }
    else if(mGetBORFlag())
    {  //Reset par mauvaise alimentation
        mClearBORFlag();
        g_stConfiguration.stats[STAT_REBOOT_NO_POWER]++;
        config_saveStats();
    }
    else if(mGetMCLRFlag())
    { //Reset par mclr (bouton reset)
        mClearMCLRFlag();
        g_stConfiguration.stats[STAT_REBOOT_OTHER]++;
        config_saveStats();
    }
    else if(mGetSWRFlag())
    {  //Reset software (non implemente encore)
        mClearSWRFlag();
        g_stConfiguration.stats[STAT_REBOOT_OTHER]++;
        config_saveStats();
    }

    /* Going to main loop */
}
```

**Flash utility functions**

```
void config_init() {
    // Lecture de la configuration presente en memoire
    nvm_lireConfig(&g_stConfiguration,NVM_PAGE_CONFIG);

    /*
     * Si le numero d'ordinateur est zero c'est parce qu'il n'y a rien dans la
    * flash, on va charger les valeurs par defaut.
    */
    if(g_stConfiguration.numero_ordinateur == 0)
    {
        config_defaut(&g_stConfiguration);
        nvm_ecrireConfig(&g_stConfiguration,NVM_PAGE_CONFIG);
        nvm_ecrireConfig(&g_stConfiguration,NVM_PAGE_CFG_BKP);
    }
}

void config_saveStats()
{
    nvm_ecrireConfig(&g_stConfiguration,NVM_PAGE_CONFIG);
}

void nvm_lireConfig(void *dataAdr, int pageNumber) {
    memcpy(dataAdr,(void*)eedata_addr[pageNumber],sizeof(ComputerConfiguration));
}

int nvm_ecrireConfig(void * dataAdr, int pageNumber) {
    int pagebuff[1024]; //Buffer d'une page, necessaire pour la fonction NVProgram

    // On efface la page avant d'ecrire dedans
    if(nvm_effacer(pageNumber) == NVM_SUCCESS) {
        // Ecriture des donnees dans la NVM
        if(NVMProgram((void*)eedata_addr[pageNumber],dataAdr,sizeof(ComputerConfiguration),(void*)pagebuff) == 0) {
            // Verification des donnees ecrits
            if(nvm_verifier(dataAdr,pageNumber) == NVM_SUCCESS) {
                return NVM_SUCCESS;
            } else {
                return NVM_VERIFY_ERROR;
            }
        } else {
            return NVM_WRITE_ERROR;
        }
    } else {
        return NVM_ERASE_ERROR;
    }
}

int nvm_effacer(int pageNumber) {
    if(pageNumber < NVM_NUM_PAGES) {
        if(NVMErasePage((void*) eedata_addr[pageNumber]) == 0) {
            return NVM_SUCCESS;
        } else {
            return NVM_ERASE_ERROR;
        }
    } else {
        return NVM_PAGE_OUT_OF_RANGE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the datasheet on this part?  Some PIC32 are 1K, others 10k endurance. Anyway, 10K / 25 = 400 days.

Comment: `NVMProgram()` erases the page automatically. So what is the purpose of `nvm_effacer()` ? Can you show us the source code of it?

Comment: @ErikFriesen problems are occuring in first days/weeks, yes I'm aware of the 10K endurance, not bothered with it for now since it doesn't look related (if problem was occuring on old units only, yes I would check more into that).

Comment: @BruceAbbott Added the missing function, please note that I've not written this code, I only have to maintain it.

Comment: There really isn’t enough info for an answer. In programming, if it can happen it will. You probably need two configs with crc so one is always valid.

Comment: @ErikFriesen That is one solution that is tested, just wondered if there was not something else I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investivation and tests, it looks like Erik Friesen was right, there was too much erase/write cycles into the flash memory.

The chip used (PIC32MX470) have a minimal cell endurance of 20000 E/W cycle (found in the datasheet page 292).

In the program I found multiple calls to the configuration write that could happen many dozens of times a day, also the erace was used twice, one manually and one into `NVMProgram`.

To confirm the issue, I've changed the pages used in the program and read / write were working perfectly (as those pages were not used before).

The final solution was :

- Cleaning the code, removing all unnecessary configuration save
- Removing the double erase
- Integrate the [Data EEPROM Emulation library](https://www.microchip.com/SWLibraryWeb/product.aspx?product=Data%20EEPROM%20Emulation%20for%20PIC) from MicroChip to extend duration even more